# codeigniter load model in core folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

I'm new with CodeIgniter and I'd like to load a model in *core/MY_Lang.php* class.

```
class MY_Lang extends CI_Lang
{
    /** array $languages Array of languages */
    var $languages = array('');

    /** array $special Special URIs (not localized) **/
    var $special = array('');

    /** string $default_uri Where to redirect if no language in URI */
    var $default_uri = '';

    public function getLanguages()
    {
        $this->load->model('Lang_model');
        return $this->Lang_model->GetLangs();
    }
```

Of course this is just an example of what I'm trying to achieve. It doesn't work and my questions are:

- is it a good practise do something like this?
- if yes, how can I load my model in that class?

Answer (score 0):

i didn't load most of core classes of CI .

the frequently used class , we load theme in **autoload.php** file instead of load them every time .

Comment: Hi. Thx for replying. I'm speaking about how to load a model in a core class though. I know that there is the autoload etc but in this case i need to know whether it is good practice and how to do that, regardless the autoload file